# Copying garbage collection of generated code

Tags: garbage-collection, jit

Copying (generational) garbage collection offers the best performance of any form of automatic memory management, but requires pointers to relocated chunks of data be fixed up. This is enabled, in languages which support this memory management technique, by disallowing pointer arithmetic and making sure all pointers are to the beginning of identifiable objects.

If you're generating code at run time with a JIT compiler, things look a bit trickier because return addresses on the call stack will point to, not the beginning of code blocks, but random locations within them, so fixup is a problem.

How is this typically solved?

Comment: I would say the code is verified before being passed to the JIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often, you *don't* relocate code. This is both because it is indeed complicated to fix the stack and other addresses (think jumps across code fragments), and because you don't actually need garbage collection for such code (as it is only manipulated by code you write anyway, so you can do manual memory management). You also don't expect to create a whole lot of machine code (compared to application objects), so fragmentation etc. is not a concern.

If you insist on moving machine code and fixing up the stack, there *is* a way, I think: Similar to Mark-Compact, build a "break table" (I have no idea where this name comes from; "relocation table" might be clearer) that tells you the amount by which you should adjust pointers to moved objects. Now, walk the stack for return addresses (highly platform-specific, of course) and fix them if they refer to relocated code. Instead of looking for exact matches, search for the highest address lower than the return address you're currently replacing. You can check that this address indeed refers to some machine code that moved by looking at the object size (you have a pointer to the start of the object, after all). This approach isn't feasible for all objects, for various reasons.

There are other reasons to do something similar though. Some JIT compilers feature *on-stack replacement*, which means creating a new version (e.g. more optimized, or less optimized) of some machine code and replacing all occurrences of the old version with it. This is far more complicated than just fixing the return addresses though. You have to ensure the new version logically continue where the old one was left hanging. I am *not* familiar with how this is implemented, so I will not go into detail.